# How can I strip stationery from incoming email in Outlook 2007?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

How can I strip stationery from incoming email in Outlook 2007? I would like to avoid using Plain Text only.

Comment: I think you should change the summary into something more clear, like: How to automatically convert incoming emails in plain text to HTML email.

Comment: I think he wants to suppress the Stationary in Incoming mail WITHOUT forcing all mail to Plain-Text,  ie he wants the formating, and graphics, just not the annoying stationary some people use to make their e-mails look like they are typed on lined paper or birthday cards.

Answer (score 3):

This following article furnishes a VBA macro that does just that :

[Microsoft Outlook 2003 Tip: VBA Macro to Remove Stationery from Email Message](http://adam.rosi-kessel.org/weblog/2008/01/26/windows-outlook-2003-tip-vba-macro-to-remove-stationery-from-email-message)

Answer (score 0):

http://www2.essex.ac.uk/cs/services/email/unwanted/

To set this filter in place, first create a folder for "Probable Spam" then run the Rules Wizard from the Tools menu in Outlook

You want to apply the rule to all incoming mail, which is the default, so click "Next"

Click the box by "suspected to be junk ...." and click "Next" (note you also have the option to define a list of sites from which you wish to block all mail. You are unlikely to want to set this now, but may do so later by modifying the rule).

Click in the box by "move it to the specified folder", setting the folder name appropriately. Then click in the box by "stop processing more rules", in order that the email is not moved from the Probable Spam folder by later rules. This is vital if you are using this rule as part of ISS's recommended rules scheme.

*Note : this is might be workaround*

Comment: I don't think he is trying to block SPAM,  just change the way some messages appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't readily change the format of all incoming email to HTML, you can change the fonts used to display plain text email so that's easier to read.

Open Tools, Options, Mail Format, Fonts dialog and change the font used for reading and replying to plain text messages.

Source: http://www.outlook-tips.net/archives/2005/20050921.htm

Answer (score 0):

In Tools | Options open the Mail Format tab - select the *Convert to HTML format* option from drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that some users over-use stationary, and it can be annoying, and hard to read.  I haven't gotten frustrated enough to investigate the solution, but my guess would be you would need to create a custom e-mail form in the Outlook Forms Manager, suppress the stationary there, and assign that form to be the reading form.